# SharePoint Newsfeed to alert everyone

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, newsfeed, social, notifications

We are using SharePoint Online (Office 365) in our company. We like the social features of the Newsfeed, however, we are, at the same time, missing the ability to alert everyone in the company if someone writes a new post. We used to have this option with Alerts feature of the Announcements list.

Is there a way to configure Newsfeed or SharePoint in general so that everyone gets an email notification if new message is posted to the Newsfeed? A solution that would not require customization or code writing would be the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately in Newsfeed, you are restricted to only to  the  below posted email notifications.

[image]

Since you are using SharePoint online, why not turn on Yammer instead of using Newsfeed features. Yammer is similar to Facebook for work and is being actively promoted by Microsoft instead of Newsfeed. At our organization and our client's, we actively use Yammer to drive social engagement.

For the question you asked, Yammer has a feature called announcements. Whenever an announcement is made, it is shown at top of the feed and also sent via Email to all Yammer users. This is all OOTB without any code use.

Regarding your question here -

> Is there a way to configure Newsfeed or SharePoint in general so that
>   everyone gets an email notification if new message is posted to the
>   Newsfeed.

Well this is not possible without code or customization.

Do a take a look here before you leap - [Yammer versus SharePoint Newsfeed. Which is right for you?](https://blog.pa.com.au/infrastructure/yammer-versus-sharepoint-newsfeed-which-is-right-for-you/)

Comment: How did you get to the Edit Details page to change the Newsfeed Settings?